# New module method in /lib not loading in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a module located in my rails app under /lib. I just added a new method to this module and want to test it out using the rails console.

I start the rails console, include the module with `include ModuleName` and then try to run the function with `function_name(parameter)`

Then I get a `NoMethodError (undefined method 'function_name' for main:Object)`

I've tried multiple ways of fixing this, it seems that having `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` in the `config/application.rb` file is the way to get the '/lib' folder loading. This does not work for me.

Does anyone know why my new method will not load in my rails console?

Additionally, I can call the method from the app via a controller. So this issue is specific to the rails console.

Comment: A hacky solution could be to type into your console: `load "#{Rails.root}/lib/yourModuleFileName.rb"`

Comment: Are you in a production environment or development?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon that did not work. TedTran2019 this is in a development environment

Answer (score 0):

You must require the file explicitly in the rails console.
`require "./lib/your_file_name.rb"`